# masonry script not executing once moved online

Tags: jquery-plugins

The following script works locally:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#content');
    alert('1');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.box',
            columnWidth : 220 
        });
        alert('2');
    });
});
</script>
```

But once I upload the site and run it online it no longer organizes the images. The masonry layout does not execute. http://jennifer2.sonnemann.ca

Thoughts? Alert number 2 does not fire so the imagesloaded event is not firing...

Chris

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to hide masonry until the images load? Also remove bootstrap.min.js from your header you don't need both bootstrap and bootstrap.min.js in there.

Comment: At this point I am just trying to get the images to line up vertically so they display in columns in a masonry pattern. Locally they tuck up nicely... when I upload it to my site and run the code the imagesloaded does not fire so they images do not organzie themselves in a masonry pattern... I suspect it is a document.ready issue... it fires before the images are ready so the loaded event is not caught.....

Comment: Once I have that working I will hide the images and then unhide once they are organzied.... one thing at a time...

Comment: Why not just do this purely in CSS?

Just hide the images by default. `#container` opacity 0 or `display:none`. By default once masonry finishes organizing the images it adds a "masonry" class to the container. So just set `#container.masonry` to `display:block` or opacity 1 or whatever you are doing.